# Good example of livelock?

Tags: concurrency, livelock

I understand what livelock is, but I was wondering if anyone had a good code-based example of it?  And by code-based, I do **not** mean "two people trying to get past each other in a corridor".  If I read that again, I'll lose my lunch.

Comment: How about a software simulation of two people trying to get past each other in a corridor?

Comment: Curse you!  I lost my lunch!

Comment: Strangely appropriate: http://seuss.wikia.com/wiki/The_Zax

Comment: Related joke for curious fellas: http://codingarchitect.wordpress.com/2006/01/18/multi-threading-basics-deadlocks-livelocks-and-starvation/

Comment: Two threads waiting for the other thread to notify is also a Live lock   isnt it ?

Comment: thread coordination is needed to have a *stable* live lock. The locking and unlocking must happen in a *deterministic* way. The easy solution is to make use of timer to coordinate threads.

Comment: Two people trying to get past each other in a corridor: https://gist.github.com/deepankarb/d2dd6f21bc49902376e614d3746b8965 :p

Comment: I see that all comment give some pseudo example but non gave a real code from a program example.

Answer (score 142):

Here's a very simple Java example of livelock where a husband and wife are trying to eat soup, but only have one spoon between them. Each spouse is too polite, and will pass the spoon if the other has not yet eaten.

```java
public class Livelock {
    static class Spoon {
        private Diner owner;
        public Spoon(Diner d) { owner = d; }
        public Diner getOwner() { return owner; }
        public synchronized void setOwner(Diner d) { owner = d; }
        public synchronized void use() { 
            System.out.printf("%s has eaten!", owner.name); 
        }
    }
    
    static class Diner {
        private String name;
        private boolean isHungry;
        
        public Diner(String n) { name = n; isHungry = true; }       
        public String getName() { return name; }
        public boolean isHungry() { return isHungry; }
        
        public void eatWith(Spoon spoon, Diner spouse) {
            while (isHungry) {
                // Don't have the spoon, so wait patiently for spouse.
                if (spoon.owner != this) {
                    try { Thread.sleep(1); } 
                    catch(InterruptedException e) { continue; }
                    continue;
                }                       
            
                // If spouse is hungry, insist upon passing the spoon.
                if (spouse.isHungry()) {                    
                    System.out.printf(
                        "%s: You eat first my darling %s!%n", 
                        name, spouse.getName());
                    spoon.setOwner(spouse);
                    continue;
                }
                
                // Spouse wasn't hungry, so finally eat
                spoon.use();
                isHungry = false;               
                System.out.printf(
                    "%s: I am stuffed, my darling %s!%n", 
                    name, spouse.getName());                
                spoon.setOwner(spouse);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Diner husband = new Diner("Bob");
        final Diner wife = new Diner("Alice");
        
        final Spoon s = new Spoon(husband);
        
        new Thread(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { husband.eatWith(s, wife); }   
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { wife.eatWith(s, husband); } 
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Run the program and you'll get:

```
Bob: You eat first my darling Alice!
Alice: You eat first my darling Bob!
Bob: You eat first my darling Alice!
Alice: You eat first my darling Bob!
Bob: You eat first my darling Alice!
Alice: You eat first my darling Bob!
...
```

This will go on forever if uninterrupted. This is a livelock because both Alice and Bob are repeatedly asking each other to go first in an infinite loop (hence *live*). In a deadlock situation, both Alice and Bob would simply be frozen waiting on each other to go first — they won't be doing anything except wait (hence *dead*).

Comment: Doesn't `getOwner` method have to be synchronized as well? From Effective Java "**synchronization has no effect unless both read and write**".

Comment: Shouldn't he use `Thread.join()` rather than `Thread.sleep()`, because he wants to wait for the spouse to do his eating?

Comment: what should we do to overcome the problem of livelock in this particular example?

Comment: @jelbourn the access to `isHungry` flag is not synchronized.

Comment: The `getOwner` method must be synchronized since even if the `setOwner` is synchronized, this does not guarantee the thread using `getOwner` (or accessing the field `owner` directly) will see the changes made by the other thread performing `setOwner`. This vid explains this very carefully: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTVooKLLVT8

Comment: You don't need to use `synchronized ` keyword for `setOwner` method , because reading and writing is atomic action for reference variable.

Comment: @Thor I think that depends on the logic we want to implement. For example we could count the times the spoon was passed and after reaching some point just gave up on insisting the spouse to eat, and eat first (this is the first logic solution that came to my mind, taken from life ;)).

Comment: @Line another way is to have a queue (usually implemented as a message queue), as it ensures there's always a priority order. Also taken from life ;) **PS:** It could also be a stack, if the situation warrants one.

Comment: @atiqkhaled the problem is one of *visibility*, not of atomicity.

Comment: Concurrency joke: "This example is also illustrating starvation"

Answer (score 83):

Flippant comments aside, one example which is known to come up is in code which tries to detect and handle deadlock situations. If two threads detect a deadlock, and try to "step aside" for each other, without care they will end up being stuck in a loop always "stepping aside" and never managing to move forwards.

By "step aside" I mean that they would release the lock and attempt to let the other one acquire it. We might imagine the situation with two threads doing this (pseudocode):

```
// thread 1
getLocks12(lock1, lock2)
{
  lock1.lock();
  while (lock2.locked())
  {
    // attempt to step aside for the other thread
    lock1.unlock();
    wait();
    lock1.lock();
  }
  lock2.lock();
}

// thread 2
getLocks21(lock1, lock2)
{
  lock2.lock();
  while (lock1.locked())
  {
    // attempt to step aside for the other thread
    lock2.unlock();
    wait();
    lock2.lock();
  }
  lock1.lock();
}
```

Race conditions aside, what we have here is a situation where both threads, if they enter at the same time will end up running in the inner loop without proceeding. Obviously this is a simplified example. A naiive fix would be to put some kind of randomness in the amount of time the threads would wait.

The proper fix is to always respect the [lock heirarchy](http://www.ddj.com/hpc-high-performance-computing/204801163?pgno=5). Pick an order in which you acquire the locks and stick to that. For example if both threads always acquire lock1 before lock2, then there is no possibility of deadlock.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that.  I'm looking for an actual code example of such.  The question is what does "step aside" mean and how does it produce such a scenario.

Comment: I get that this is a contrived example but is it likely that this could lead to a livelock? Wouldn't it be much more likely that eventually a window would open where one function could grab both, due to inconsistencies in the time the threads are aloud to run and when they are scheduled.

Comment: Although it isn't a stable livelock because they will obviously break out of it eventually, I think it fits the description well enough

Comment: Excellent and meaningful example.

Answer (score 8):

As there is no answer marked as accepted answer, I have attempted to create live lock example;

[Original program](https://articlestack.wordpress.com/2016/01/23/java-multithreading-final-program/) was written by me in Apr 2012 to learn various concept of multithreading. This time I have modified it to create deadlock, race condition, livelock etc.

So let's understand the problem statement first;

**Cookie Maker Problem**

There are some ingredient containers: **ChocoPowederContainer**, **WheatPowderContainer**. **CookieMaker** takes some amount of powder from ingredient containers to bake a **Cookie**. If a cookie maker finds a container empty it checks for another container to save time. And waits until **Filler** fills the required container. There is a **Filler** who checks container on regular interval and fills some quantity if a container needs it.

Please check the complete code on [github](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/Practical-Java/tree/master/Concurrency/src/os/nushi/concurrency/cookiemaking2);

Let me explain you implementation in brief.

- I start **Filler** as daemon thread. So it'll keep filling containers on regular interval. To fill a container first it locks the container -> check if it needs some powder -> fills it -> signal all makers who are waiting for it -> unlock container.
- I create **CookieMaker** and set that it can bake up to 8 cookies in parallel. And I start 8 threads to bake cookies.
- Each maker thread creates 2 callable sub-thread to take powder from containers.
- sub-thread takes a lock on a container and check if it has enough powder. If not, wait for some time. Once Filler fills the container, it takes the powder, and unlock the container.
- Now it completes other activities like: making mixture and baking etc.

Let's have a look in the code:

**CookieMaker.java**

```
private Integer getMaterial(final Ingredient ingredient) throws Exception{
        :
        container.lock();
        while (!container.getIngredient(quantity)) {
            container.empty.await(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            //Thread.sleep(500); //For deadlock
        }
        container.unlock();
        :
}
```

**IngredientContainer.java**

```
public boolean getIngredient(int n) throws Exception {
    :
    lock();
    if (quantityHeld >= n) {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        quantityHeld -= n;
        unlock();
        return true;
    }
    unlock();
    return false;
}
```

Everything runs fine until **Filler** is filling the containers. But if I forget to start the filler, or filler goes on unexpected leave, sub-threads keep changing their states to allow other maker to go and check the container.

I have also create a daemon [ThreadTracer](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/Practical-Java/blob/master/Concurrency/src/os/nushi/concurrency/tracer/Tracer.java) which keeps watch on thread states and deadlocks. This the output from console;

```
2016-09-12 21:31:45.065 :: [Maker_0:WAITING, Maker_1:WAITING, Maker_2:WAITING, Maker_3:WAITING, Maker_4:WAITING, Maker_5:WAITING, Maker_6:WAITING, Maker_7:WAITING, pool-7-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-7-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-8-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-8-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-6-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-6-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-5-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-5-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-1-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-3-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-2-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-1-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-4-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-4-thread-2:RUNNABLE, pool-3-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-2-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING]
2016-09-12 21:31:45.065 :: [Maker_0:WAITING, Maker_1:WAITING, Maker_2:WAITING, Maker_3:WAITING, Maker_4:WAITING, Maker_5:WAITING, Maker_6:WAITING, Maker_7:WAITING, pool-7-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-7-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-8-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-8-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-6-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-6-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-5-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-5-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-1-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-3-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-2-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-1-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-4-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-4-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-3-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-2-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING]
WheatPowder Container has 0 only.
2016-09-12 21:31:45.082 :: [Maker_0:WAITING, Maker_1:WAITING, Maker_2:WAITING, Maker_3:WAITING, Maker_4:WAITING, Maker_5:WAITING, Maker_6:WAITING, Maker_7:WAITING, pool-7-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-7-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-8-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-8-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-6-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-6-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-5-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-5-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-1-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-3-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-2-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-1-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-4-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-4-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-3-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-2-thread-2:RUNNABLE]
2016-09-12 21:31:45.082 :: [Maker_0:WAITING, Maker_1:WAITING, Maker_2:WAITING, Maker_3:WAITING, Maker_4:WAITING, Maker_5:WAITING, Maker_6:WAITING, Maker_7:WAITING, pool-7-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-7-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-8-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-8-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-6-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-6-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-5-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-5-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-1-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-3-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-2-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-1-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-4-thread-1:TIMED_WAITING, pool-4-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-3-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING, pool-2-thread-2:TIMED_WAITING]
```

You'll notice that sub-threads and changing their states and waiting.

Answer (score 6):

A real (albeit without exact code) example is two competing processes live locking in an attempt to correct for a SQL server deadlock, with each process using the same wait-retry algorithm for retrying. While it's the luck of timing, I have seen this happen on separate machines with similar performance characteristics in response to a message added to an EMS topic (e.g. saving an update of a single object graph more than once), and not being able to control the lock order.

A good solution in *this* case would be to have competing consumers (prevent duplicate processing as high up in the chain as possible by partitioning the work on unrelated objects).

A less desirable (ok, dirty-hack) solution is to break the timing bad luck (kind of force differences in processing) in advance or break it after deadlock by using different algorithms or some element of randomness. This could still have issues because its possible the lock taking order is "sticky" for each process, and this takes a certain minimum of time not accounted for in the wait-retry.

Yet another solution (at least for SQL Server) is to try a different isolation level (e.g. snapshot).

Answer (score 2):

I coded up the example of 2 persons passing in a corridor. The two threads will avoid each other as soon as they realise their directions are the same.

```
public class LiveLock {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Object left = new Object();
        Object right = new Object();
        Pedestrian one = new Pedestrian(left, right, 0); //one's left is one's left
        Pedestrian two = new Pedestrian(right, left, 1); //one's left is two's right, so have to swap order
        one.setOther(two);
        two.setOther(one);
        one.start();
        two.start();
    }
}

class Pedestrian extends Thread {
    private Object l;
    private Object r;
    private Pedestrian other;
    private Object current;

    Pedestrian (Object left, Object right, int firstDirection) {
        l = left;
        r = right;
        if (firstDirection==0) {
            current = l;
        }
        else {
            current = r;
        }
    }

    void setOther(Pedestrian otherP) {
        other = otherP;
    }

    Object getDirection() {
        return current;
    }

    Object getOppositeDirection() {
        if (current.equals(l)) {
            return r;
        }
        else {
            return l;
        }
    }

    void switchDirection() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        current = getOppositeDirection();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is stepping aside.");
    }

    public void run() {
        while (getDirection().equals(other.getDirection())) {
            try {
                switchDirection();
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C# version of jelbourn's code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LiveLockExample
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var husband = new Diner("Bob");
            var wife = new Diner("Alice");

            var s = new Spoon(husband);

            Task.WaitAll(
                Task.Run(() => husband.EatWith(s, wife)),
                Task.Run(() => wife.EatWith(s, husband))
                );
        }

        public class Spoon
        {
            public Spoon(Diner diner)
            {
                Owner = diner;
            }


            public Diner Owner { get; private set; }

            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
            public void SetOwner(Diner d) { Owner = d; }

            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
            public void Use()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} has eaten!", Owner.Name);
            }
        }

        public class Diner
        {
            public Diner(string n)
            {
                Name = n;
                IsHungry = true;
            }

            public string Name { get; private set; }

            private bool IsHungry { get; set; }

            public void EatWith(Spoon spoon, Diner spouse)
            {
                while (IsHungry)
                {
                    // Don't have the spoon, so wait patiently for spouse.
                    if (spoon.Owner != this)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(1);
                        }
                        catch (ThreadInterruptedException e)
                        {
                        }

                        continue;
                    }

                    // If spouse is hungry, insist upon passing the spoon.
                    if (spouse.IsHungry)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}: You eat first my darling {1}!", Name, spouse.Name);
                        spoon.SetOwner(spouse);
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Spouse wasn't hungry, so finally eat
                    spoon.Use();
                    IsHungry = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: I am stuffed, my darling {1}!", Name, spouse.Name);
                    spoon.SetOwner(spouse);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider a UNIX system having 50 process slots.

Ten programs are running, each of which having to create 6 (sub)processes.

After each process has created 4 processes, the 10 original processes and the 40 new processes have exhausted the table. Each of the 10 original processes now sits in an endless loop forking and failing – which is aptly the situation of a livelock. The probability of this happening is very little but it could happen.

Answer (score 1):

One example here might be using a timed tryLock to obtain more than one lock and if you can't obtain them all, back off and try again.

```
boolean tryLockAll(Collection<Lock> locks) {
  boolean grabbedAllLocks = false;
  for(int i=0; i<locks.size(); i++) {
    Lock lock = locks.get(i);
    if(!lock.tryLock(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
      grabbedAllLocks = false;

      // undo the locks I already took in reverse order
      for(int j=i-1; j >= 0; j--) {
        lock.unlock();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I could imagine such code would be problematic as you have lots of threads colliding and waiting to obtain a set of locks.  But I'm not sure this is very compelling to me as a simple example.

Comment: for this to be a livelock you'll need another thread to acquire those locks in a different order.  If all the threads use `tryLockAll()` with the locks in `locks` in the same order, there is no livelock.

Answer (score 1):

Python version of jelbourn's code:

```
import threading
import time
lock = threading.Lock()

class Spoon:
    def __init__(self, diner):
        self.owner = diner

    def setOwner(self, diner):
        with lock:
            self.owner = diner

    def use(self):
        with lock:
            "{0} has eaten".format(self.owner)

class Diner:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hungry = True

    def eatsWith(self, spoon, spouse):
        while(self.hungry):
            if self != spoon.owner:
                time.sleep(1) # blocks thread, not process
                continue

            if spouse.hungry:
                print "{0}: you eat first, {1}".format(self.name, spouse.name)
                spoon.setOwner(spouse)
                continue

            # Spouse was not hungry, eat
            spoon.use()
            print "{0}: I'm stuffed, {1}".format(self.name, spouse.name)
            spoon.setOwner(spouse)

def main():
    husband = Diner("Bob")
    wife = Diner("Alice")
    spoon = Spoon(husband)

    t0 = threading.Thread(target=husband.eatsWith, args=(spoon, wife))
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=wife.eatsWith, args=(spoon, husband))
    t0.start()
    t1.start()
    t0.join()
    t1.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Bugs: in use(), print is not used and - more importantly - the hungry flag is not set to False.

Answer (score 0):

I modify the answer of @jelbourn.
When one of them notices that the other is hungry, he(her) should release the spoon and wait another notify, so a livelock happens.

```
public class LiveLock {
    static class Spoon {
        Diner owner;

        public String getOwnerName() {
            return owner.getName();
        }

        public void setOwner(Diner diner) {
            this.owner = diner;
        }

        public Spoon(Diner diner) {
            this.owner = diner;
        }

        public void use() {
            System.out.println(owner.getName() + " use this spoon and finish eat.");
        }
    }

    static class Diner {
        public Diner(boolean isHungry, String name) {
            this.isHungry = isHungry;
            this.name = name;
        }

        private boolean isHungry;
        private String name;


        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void eatWith(Diner spouse, Spoon sharedSpoon) {
            try {
                synchronized (sharedSpoon) {
                    while (isHungry) {
                        while (!sharedSpoon.getOwnerName().equals(name)) {
                            sharedSpoon.wait();
                            //System.out.println("sharedSpoon belongs to" + sharedSpoon.getOwnerName())
                        }
                        if (spouse.isHungry) {
                            System.out.println(spouse.getName() + "is hungry,I should give it to him(her).");
                            sharedSpoon.setOwner(spouse);
                            sharedSpoon.notifyAll();
                        } else {
                            sharedSpoon.use();
                            sharedSpoon.setOwner(spouse);
                            isHungry = false;
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(name + " is interrupted.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Diner husband = new Diner(true, "husband");
        final Diner wife = new Diner(true, "wife");
        final Spoon sharedSpoon = new Spoon(wife);

        Thread h = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                husband.eatWith(wife, sharedSpoon);
            }
        };
        h.start();

        Thread w = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                wife.eatWith(husband, sharedSpoon);
            }
        };
        w.start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        h.interrupt();
        w.interrupt();

        try {
            h.join();
            w.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package concurrently.deadlock;

import static java.lang.System.out;


/* This is an example of livelock */
public class Dinner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Spoon spoon = new Spoon();
        Dish dish = new Dish();

        new Thread(new Husband(spoon, dish)).start();
        new Thread(new Wife(spoon, dish)).start();
    }
}


class Spoon {
    boolean isLocked;
}

class Dish {
    boolean isLocked;
}

class Husband implements Runnable {

    Spoon spoon;
    Dish dish;

    Husband(Spoon spoon, Dish dish) {
        this.spoon = spoon;
        this.dish = dish;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            synchronized (spoon) {
                spoon.isLocked = true;
                out.println("husband get spoon");
                try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

                if (dish.isLocked == true) {
                    spoon.isLocked = false; // give away spoon
                    out.println("husband pass away spoon");
                    continue;
                }
                synchronized (dish) {
                    dish.isLocked = true;
                    out.println("Husband is eating!");

                }
                dish.isLocked = false;
            }
            spoon.isLocked = false;
        }
    }
}

class Wife implements Runnable {

    Spoon spoon;
    Dish dish;

    Wife(Spoon spoon, Dish dish) {
        this.spoon = spoon;
        this.dish = dish;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (dish) {
                dish.isLocked = true;
                out.println("wife get dish");
                try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

                if (spoon.isLocked == true) {
                    dish.isLocked = false; // give away dish
                    out.println("wife pass away dish");
                    continue;
                }
                synchronized (spoon) {
                    spoon.isLocked = true;
                    out.println("Wife is eating!");

                }
                spoon.isLocked = false;
            }
            dish.isLocked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

**Thread 1**

```
top:
lock(L1);                
if (try_lock(L2) != 0) {
  unlock(L1);
goto top;
```

**Thread 2**

```
top:
lock(L2);
if (try_lock(L1) != 0) {
    unlock(L2);
goto top;
```

The only difference is Thread 1 and Thread 2 try to acquire the locks in a different order.  Livelock could happen as follows:

Thread 1 runs acquires L1, then a context switch occurs.  Thread 2 runs acquires L2, then another context switch occurs.  Thread 1 runs and cannot acquire L2, but before releasing L1 a context switch occurs.  Thread 2 runs and cannot acquire L1, releases L2, and a context switch occurs.  Thread 1 releases L1, and now we are basically back to the starting state, and in theory these steps could keep repeating forever.