# TThread.Synchronize Makes Form Freezes

Tags: delphi, tthread

I'm checking how write to a Memo from a thread as safe mode.
The problem is, when using `TThread.Synchronize` it make form freezes, and without that Form works good.

Here is the code who freeze:

```
procedure TestThread;
var
  x : Integer;
begin
  for x := 0 to 2 do
  begin
    TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      while True do
      begin
        TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread, procedure
        begin
          //CritLock.Acquire;
          try
            Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Add to Memo ' + IntToStr(GetTickCount));
          finally
            //CritLock.Release;
          end;
        end);
      end;
    end).Start;
  end;
end;
```

and here the code who don't freeze:

```
procedure TestThread;
    var
      x : Integer;
    begin
      for x := 0 to 2 do
      begin
        TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
        procedure
        begin
          while True do
          begin
            //CritLock.Acquire;
            try
              Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Add to Memo ' + IntToStr(GetTickCount));
            finally
              //CritLock.Release;
            end;
          end;
        end).Start;
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: if add SleepEx(1, False); inside while True, form runs good. so need at least one sleep?

Comment: I think you're getting a [livelock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155951/whats-the-difference-between-deadlock-and-livelock).

Comment: You're confused about what Synchronize does, and also seem unaware that your second example is not valid code. All UI access has to happen in the main thread (the reason  that Synchronize exists), and your second example violates that rule. Your first example is flawed because you seem to not know that calling Synchronize pauses the thread, switches to the main thread, performs the work in the method being synchronized, and then switches back to the thread. You're hammering the form with calls to Synchronize constantly, which means that the threads are spending all their time changing context.

Comment: If you're changing thread contexts constantly, it's pretty much impossible to get anything else done. Try it yourself - set two large towels on the floor, a couple feet apart. Stand on one, and then start continuously jumping back and forth between them non-stop. Now try to type an email to your mother or write a shopping list using a pen and paper while still constantly jumping back and forth. You might get a character or two squeezed in between hops, but not much more. Now make it worse, like your first code does. You're only allowed to write or type when you're on the towel you started on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your 1st example is technically correct, the worker threads are safely updating the Memo in a proper way.

The problem is, they are updating it TOO MUCH.  Your threads are running continuous loops at full speed, flooding the main thread's message queue with synchronization requests, making it nearly impossible for the main thread to handle other UI messages in a timely manner, such as painting the UI.

The sleep helps by slowing down the worker threads to give the main thread some much-needed breathing space to do other things in between syncs.  In real-world production code, worker threads would not be slamming the UI with updates as hard as you are doing. They would be doing other meaningful work and notifying the UI with status updates only when needed.